# PHP - Codeigniter not found CI_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller{
    public function index(){
        echo "WELCOME CONTROLLER";
    }
}

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once APPPATH . 'core/MYC_Controller.php';
class Frontend_Controller extends MYC_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "<br /> Frontend Controller<br />";
    }
}

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MYC_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "<br />MY Controller<br />";
    }
}
```

On my local server it works fine. but on hosting it has problems.

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in 
/home/vol7_5/byethost3.com/b3_15049873/htdocs/application/core/MYC_Controller.php on line 2
```

I don't have an idea whats wrong. When I'm including in MYC_Controller - CI_Controller it says:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CI_Controller in 
/home/vol7_5/byethost3.com/b3_15049873/htdocs/system/core/Controller.php on line 30
```

Comment: In the constructor of MYC_Controller and Frontend_Controller, add `parent::__construct();`
Also what is the value of `$config['subclass_prefix']` in `application/config/congfig.php`?

Comment: subclass_prefix value is MY_